# Javascript, Forms, and Describe

Tags: visualforce, javascript, describesobject

One of the advantages of using Visualforce is the magic that happens when building forms.  When you use an `<apex:inputField>` component (particularly when in an `<apex:pageBlockSection>`, Salesforce does all of this for you automatically:

- Chooses the correct input type based on field type
- For picklists, shows the correct picklist options (further controlled by record type & picklist dependencies)
- Shows the correct label next to the input (possibly translated by locale)
- Shows the correct help text as a hover orb
- Gives a UI hint to show that the field is required

When we're building javascript-driven client side apps, (using Angular, React, Backbone, or whatever tool we choose) we don't get any of that out of the box.

I've been experimenting with pulling `describe` information into javascript (typically by serializing from Apex into JSON and sending it into my app), but I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel.  I imagine many of us are doing this, would love to poll for best practices and effective patterns.

**How do you pull describe information into javascript to avoid hard-coding information that we set declaratively in Salesforce?**

*Note: my highest priority are labels & help texts.  I'm resigned to manually creating my input elements -- and often want more control than 'salesforce defaults' for those anyway...*

Comment: I've done the labels as part of a config object my Angular code pulls from a custom REST service that does Apex describes. Unfortunately the Apex API is incomplete in the area of [Picklist values by record type for AngularJS UI](https://force201.wordpress.com/2015/06/01/picklist-values-by-record-type-for-angularjs-ui/) though. There isn't a 1:1 mapping between the configuration Salesforce allows and the types of UI you want to build in a client-side app so I think it's going to remain a pragmatic decision on how much of the Salesforce information to consume.